# Angular 7 app gives error for Mac client (only) in production release (only)

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core

I have an Angular 7 application created via Visual Studio. It uses Entity Framework to do data access. When I connect a laptop to my development version of the application in IIS Express, everything works great. This is the same whether I use a Windows laptop or a MacBook Air (Chrome or Safari).

However, when I do a production release to my local IIS, while everything works fine for Windows clients, I get an error (EntityValidationErrors) when attempting a login from the MacBook (Chrome or Safari). All Windows clients work fine, and always have. Only recently have we needed to support Macs.

Looking at the Network tab of Chrome, I can see that, with the production release, the Mac clients are posting something different to the login method than PC clients. Here is the login screen:

[image]

And here is what is posted from any Windows client:

[image]

But from the MacBook, what is posted is this:

[image]

You can see that no "pwd" property is included, and instead an "allowRememberMe" with a true value is being submitted. (This is a value that should not be populated once cookies are cleared, which I did - it comes from the server on a successful login, and is later saved as a cookie.) The strange thing is that the Mac client posts the same exact payload when connecting to the development web site, but there is no error in that case - the login works perfectly.

On the MacBook, I can see, from the initiator sub-tab of the network tab, that the error comes from the polyfills.[xxx].js file, but that is just one big line and I can't guess where the problem may lie.

I just don't know how to go about debugging this problem. (I've rarely used a Mac before today.) I'm guessing it is something to do with polyfills, since that is the file the error is coming from, but that doesn't get me anywhere. (This is a big, complex application and I don't have any way to replicate the problem on StackBlitz.)

Can anyone offer me some advice on how to go about figuring out why all Mac clients are getting errors, on any browser, when going to the production build?

(I have been trying to connect to the w3wp.exe process of IIS to do remote debugging and see what is happening in the server code (C#), but no luck so far. Breakpoints appear to be set (filled red circles), but are never hit.)

Here is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vIDix.Control.Web": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vIDix.Control.Web:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "vIDix.Control.Web:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vIDix.Control.Web:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "vIDix.Control.Web-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "vIDix.Control.Web:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "vIDix.Control.Web",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    },
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "spec": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vIDix.Control.Web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.13",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "0.17.3",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular-split": "3.0.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "2.0.5",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "luxon": "1.16.0",
    "mat-table-exporter": "1.2.5",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "ng2-date-picker": "2.12.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "8.1.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.1.0",
    "ngx-custom-validators": "7.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my remote debugging working, and it turned out that this issue was the result of device information being passed by the client on the Mac. It was one character too long for the table where the information was stored. I should have gotten that working before posting - sorry.